# where can I find application specific context.xml file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, context.xml

I read that `context.xml` file *(in Tomcat)* is application specific. I have created two web projects from my netbeans IDE with Tomcat as the server.But I unable to find the application specific `context.xml` files. I have only found the `context.xml` inside the *conf* directory of Tomcat.

[image]

Where can I find the application specific `context.xml` files ?

Comment: application specific `context.xml` isn't inside `META-INF/context.xml` of the project/war file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the link in the other answer is for the wrong version of Tomcat. Here is the correct documentation:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

As you can see the options are different now from previous versions. In my experience the most common is options 1:

```
In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files.
```

Comment: I do not see any directory named _application files_

Comment: application specific `context.xml` isn't inside `META-INF/context.xml` ?

Comment: I am saying that *is* the most common location for application-specific `context.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience and what i see from the documentation:

> ```
> Context elements may be explicitly defined:
> ```
>
> - In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file: the Context element
>     information will be loaded by all webapps.
> - In the
>     $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default file:
>     the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps of that
>     host.

Taken from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: As you can see in the picture pasted above,I do not have the catalina directory there. In this case what do I do ?

Comment: application specific `context.xml` isn't inside `META-INF/context.xml` ?

Comment: The first option above is not application-specific. The second would be, for example, conf/Catalina/localhost/yourappname.xml. The file and its parent directories, if they don't yet exist, are created when you deploy the war. This approach lets you configure two instances of the same war differently. A third option is to use the context.xml inside the war itself.