# I do not have the catalina directory in the Tomcat folder. In this case where can i find application specific context.xml file?

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina, context.xml

I have two projects with working server as `Tomcat`. [From their website](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html),I came to know that application specific `context.xml` files are located inside the catalina/localhost directory.

I do not have the *catalina* directory in the Tomcat folder. I have installed Tomcat with netbeans. In this case where can I locate the `context.xml` for each application ?

[image]

***Note : This question may be linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561961/where-can-i-find-application-specific-context-xml-file) but they are different***

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with your question, but if you are referring to each specific application folder, you can find it under :

```
work\Catalina\localhost\{yourappwebcontext}
```

Otherwise you are referring to $CATALINA_HOME or $CATALINA_BASE which is actually  your tomcat installation path. You can set this in your environment variables also, i.e :

```
c:/program files/apacheTomcatFoundation/ApacheTomcat7.0.22
```

Comment: the website says `In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps of that host.` I do not have engine name in the conf directory

Comment: work directory is empty initially, and once the first request come, it will start to be populated. Enginename and hostname have to be configured in server.xml, but usually this is being created only if you need VirtualHosting ( one server acts to serve multiple domain names). By default your Enginename is Catalina and your host is localhost. Refer to http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html )

Comment: I also have a context.xml inside the `META-INF` folder of the project/war. Isn't that the application specific context.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

the website says In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps of that host. I do not have engine name in the conf directory